# Inserting HTML and PHP into a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, innerhtml

I'm currently working with a Wordpress plugin. I have amended one of the plugin files by adding some simple HTML code and a PHP variable associated with the plugin. Essentially duplicating a piece of code already in the file so I can repurpose the code using simple CSS.

(Essentially, the plugin dynamically displays the grand total of a product as different features are added. I just needed to duplicate this and display it as a fixed banner, so nothing in the plugin file I have added is new or changes the way the plugin functions.)

I'd like to be able to append this code using javascript so that when I update the plugin, my changes won't be lost.

This is what I have so far but I've had no success so far

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var el = document.createElement("div");
el.innerHTML = "<div class="gt-banner-message">
    <div class="total-wrap">
            <span><?php _e('Grand total: ','advanced-product-fields-for-woocommerce'); ?></span>
            <span class="wapf-grand-total price amount"></span>
        </div>
    </div> ";
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("wapf-product-totals");
insertAfter(div, el);
```

Can someone let me know where I maybe going wrong here. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: `el.innerHTML = "<div class="` - that's where that string value starts and ends, after that comes gibberish that invalidates the syntax. And text literals in single or double quotes can not go across multiple lines in JS to begin with.

Comment: You need to fix the quotes issue. You cannot call PHP to run from a JS div ...:) doesn't work that way ... what you can do is call that data from before the JS runs... to a PHP variable and display it with JS - you can run this PHP function and return it to a PHP var like: $productFields and in JS var DatafromPHP = '<?php echo $productFields;?>' -- this applies if the output of the function is this a text string.

Comment: @Shlomtzion Thanks for the reply. So are you saying that the php content inside the span in my code above would need to be declared even before the js function?

Comment: Yes, get the data on PHP that runs before the JS and use it with JS.